# Integral additive for extended integrable functions.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. A function $f : X \to [-\infty, \infty]$ is called an *extended $\mu$-integrable* function if at least one of $\int f^{+} d\mu$ and $\int f^{-} d\mu$ is finite, where $f^{+} = \max(f,0)$ and $f^{-} = \max(-f,0)$.

For functions in $L^{1}(\mu)$ the integral is additive. I am wondering if this is also true for extended integrable functions $f$ and $g$ (provided that for both f and g simultaneously, either the positive integral or the negative integral is bounded).

Concretely, suppose $f$ and $g$ are extended $\mu$-integrable functions such that both $\int f^{-} d\mu < \infty$ and $\int g^{-} d\mu < \infty$. Does it then follow that $\int(f+g)d\mu = \int fd\mu + \int g d\mu$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if both $\int f^+ d\mu$ and $\int g^+ d\mu$ are finite, the result is the usual one. Otherwise both sides are $+\infty$ so they are still equal:

Suppose $\int f^+ = +\infty$ and $f^+$ is approxiamted by $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k 1_{A_k}$  from below and $g^-$ is approximated by $T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k 1_{B_k}$ from above, then we have $f^+ \geq S_n$ and $g^- \leq T_n$ and $\int S_n \to \int f^+$ and $\int T_n \to \int g^-$.

Since $(f+g)^+ \geq f^+ - g^- \geq S_n - T_n$ and $\int (S_n - T_n)d\mu$ goes to $+\infty$ we see $\int(f+g)^+ \to +\infty$

Comment: Could you explain why $\int(f+g) = \infty $ given that one of $\int f^{+}$ and $\int g^{+} = \infty$.

Comment: @unknownymous suppose $\int f^+ = \infty$, then the simple functions we use to approximate $f^+$ has an integral going to infinity.. And $(f+g)^+ \geq f^+ - g^-$. Since the simple function we use to approximate $g^-$ has a finite integral, we see that the simple function we use to approximate $(f+g)^+$ has an integral going to $+\infty$

Comment: @unknownymous I've edited.

Comment: I don't think you can always approximate by simple functions from above. Ex: $\chi_{(0,3]}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: @unknownymous We define the value of integral through its approximation by simple functions, right? Otherwise how do you define the integral?

Comment: I agree with that, but I don't agree that for any function $g$ (even with bounded integral), you can find a simple function $T$ such that $g \leq T$.

Comment: @unknownymous $g^-$ is integrable so is $2g^-$, $2g^-$ can be approximated from below and some of the approximations for $2g^-$satisfy $g^- < T$. Or take a finite measure and consider approximation from below for $g^- + 1$

Comment: I think this is false for the example I wrote above.

Comment: @unknownymous if we use an infinite sum of indicator function?